# Con que librería y como puedo hacer una petición HTTP en C++

Tags: c++, http, c++11, c++17

¿Quisiera saber como puedo hacer una petición HTTP en C++?

Comment: Consulta esto: [http en c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011339/how-do-you-make-a-http-request-with-c)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No puedo hacer un comentario rápido porque no tengo suficiente reputación, pero esta [libreria](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk) es la mejor para ello. Un ejemplo aqui:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cpprest/http_client.h>

using namespace web::http;                  
using namespace web::http::client;          

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    http_client client("http://httpbin.org/");

    http_response response;
    response = client.request(methods::GET, "/get").get();
    std::cout << response.extract_string().get() << "\n";

    response = client.request(methods::GET, "/get").get();
    std::cout << "url: " << response.extract_json().get()[U("url")] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: ¿por qué dices que es la mejor?, te recomendaria evitar dar un un juicio de valor sin sustentarlo. ;)

Comment: Porque es la más documentada, más rápida y está hecha por microsoft, que más quieres?

Comment: Yo solo quiero una respuesta objetiva, ¿ante qué métrica usted señala que es más rápida y con que otras librerías las has comparado?, lo de la documentación es discutible, y lo de microsoft no tiene sentido. Por ultimo no te pongas a la defensiva, solo soy un usuario curioso que quiere aprender :)

Comment: La api de microsoft esta diseñada para funcionar de manera asíncrona y he comparado los tiempos con request sencillos ante librerias como curlpp y el tiempo de respuesta es considerablemente inferior. Si lo de la documentación es discutible para ti entonces no me detendré ahí a darte una explicación, tampoco con lo de microsoft

Comment: Sería genial que compartas tus test :), dije que la documentación es discutible porque la mayoria librerías conocidas tienen una buena documentación. y lo de microsoft señalo que es irrelevante porque es una empresa, y que el software que implemente dicha empresa no implica que sea la mejor, ¿y para los usuarios de otras OS?

Comment: Veo que no seguiste el enlace de la libreria que dejé, al parecer no eres tan curioso. Está diseñada para ser usada en Windows, Linux, OSX y Android. Y no, no es cierto que toda libreria conocida tiene buena documentación, te doy como ejemplo RxTx en Java, ni siquiera tiene javadocs

Comment: Genial, lo voy a revisar, no seas tan sarcástico en tus respuestas, muchas veces va a ser tomado de mala forma en SO, lee el [nuevo código de conducta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/conduct), gracias por las respuestas :)

Comment: Perdona, no trataba de serlo

Comment: Hay frase de más, por ejemplo *que más quieres?*, no era necesario, considera que no conozco esa librería y no asumas que los demás lo conozcan, *al parecer no eres tan curioso*, innecesaria. Si los evitas en la conversación sería mucho más agradable. :)

Comment: Perdona, de donde vengo esa frase es interpretada de manera amigable, pero entiendo lo que dices. Tendré cuidado para la próxima

Comment: Termino con esto: no es lo mismo una conversación cara a cara que hacerlo por medio de un chat. :), adios